# Is it possible to update UI on a background thread?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Consider the situation of Sketch (or some other drawing tool), where you can select and drag objects, and an inspector appears with info about the selected object.

[image]

Now it's easy to implement dragging (just update object's frame) and it's easy to implement inspector (just update elements to show data about object  - using ReactiveSwift for this.)

But **updating inspector takes at least 50ms**. It's doing autolayout calculations I presume, as the layout changes a bit. If I update inspector on **mouseDown**, and I start dragging the object right away, there is a visible lag with the dragging.

So you move your mouse, but the object stays in place for 50ms, until inspector updates - it's just annoying.

**Is it possible to change object's frame and at the same time update inspector?** Or somehow run the autolayout calculations on the background thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot update UI on background thread. But you can update both the frame of the dragged object and your equivalent of the inspector at the same time on the main thread.

If this particular app isn't updating both at the same time, then that's just how they chose to implement it. Likely, they're trying to differentiate between dragging and tapping (common behavior when you need to differentiate between the two types of gestures), which results is a slight lag before the pan is recognized. (This is important because you often don't want a tap to be mistaken for a small pan.) There are lots of other reasons they may have done it this way.

But it's hard to say without seeing their implementation. But you don't have to do it that way in your app if you don't want.